# Meaning of "do a little voodoo"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does it mean *do a little voodoo*? I have seen this expression in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter) by *Bryan Oakley* on *StackOverFlow*:

> To use these, though, you need to do a little voodoo to get this
>   information passed to your validate command.

Intuitively, this expression could possibly mean for me:

- Do a workaround (cheat)
- Do something that is hard or tedious (or both)

Comment: Hopefully this will help:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViftZTfRSt8

Comment: Could you please stop using coding format on ELL? It has no place here and is highly discouraged, as many find it annoying and that it makes questions or answers or comments difficult to read.

Answer (score 7):

"To do a little vodoo" here means to do something "mysterious" which leads to the desired result. To the uninitated - or here: the less apt programmer - the way the problem was solved seems "magic".

With other words, he says he's about to do / show a nifty little programming trick that's either unusual or very ingenious.

Comment: You're completely correct, but I'd just like to add that the term "magic" used in the software field usually means that something is completely unknowable or inaccessible. For instance, "magic number" refers to a number variable assigned a constant in the source code -- i.e. `x = 150`. This number is "magic" because the only way anyone could ever know how "x" became "150" is if they had complete access to your source code, which usually doesn't happen. Unless a value never changes, variables should be set using some kind of external configuration. See also "black box" technology.